# What do 了 and 好 indicate in ...别人用了我们的赠品，觉得好...?

Tags: word, particles

There's a line like this:

> 高个儿拍了拍脑袋，“你的意思是说，别人用**了**我们的赠品，觉得**好**，就自然会找我们买？”

Why is there 了 in the 别人用了我们的赠品?

Does this sentence indicate something about completion of an action or something in the past?

I don't think so though.

And then, what does 好 behind 觉得 indicate? Does the whole phrase mean "think well"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this sentence indicate something about completion of an action or something in the past?

'verb + 了' indicate the verb is completed, but it doesn't indicate any tense, It can be in the past or in the future.

Example:

昨天我(吃了)就睡 - I slept after I ate yesterday

現在我(吃了)又要去睡 - now I've eaten, I have to sleep again

明天我(吃了)還是要去睡 - I will still sleep after I've eaten tomorrow.

In all three sentences, 了 only indicate the action 吃 is completed.

> 别人用了我们的赠品，觉得好

'If' is implied.

如果(if) 别人(people) 用了 (used) 我们的赠品 (our gifts)，觉得好 (consider it is good)

别人(people) 用了 (used) 我们的赠品 (our gifts)，如果(if they) 觉得好 (consider it is good)

Answer (score 1):

“

```
高个儿拍了拍脑袋，“你的意思是说，别人用了我们的赠品，觉得好，就自然会找我们买？”
```

Why is there 了 in the 别人用了我们的赠品?”
“了”just means the verb action is completed before the action of the next verb or sentence, It is not referenced to the time when the speaker speaks.